# What data structure and algorithms to use to optimize concurrent jobs?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures

I have a series of file-watchers that trigger jobs. The file-watchers look, every fixed interval of time, in their list and, if they find a file, they trigger a job. If not, they wait, coming back after that mentioned interval.

Some jobs are dependent on others, so running them in a proper order and with proper parallelism would be a good optimization. But I do not want to think about this myself.

**What data structure and algorithms should I use to ask a computer to tell me what job to assign to what file-watcher (and in what order to put them)?**

As input, I have the dependencies between the jobs, the arrival time of files for each job and a number of watchers. (For starter, I will pretend each jobs takes same amount of time). How do I spread the jobs between the watchers, to avoid unnecessary waiting gaps and to obtain faster run time?

(I am looking forward tackling this optimization in an algorithmic way, but would like to start with some expert advice)

EDIT : so far I understood the fact the I need a DAG ([Directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph#cite_note-hgt1181-31)) to represent the dependencies and that I need to play with [Topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) in order to optimize. But this responds with a one execution line, one thread. What if I have more, say 7?

Comment: Would an existing tool like http://gittup.org/tup/ work?  If not, maybe it gives you some ideas.

Comment: Certainly separate the file-watching operation from the rest of the concepts... it's an embarassingly parallel operation that's I/O heavy, and you don't need that complicating the job execution and dependency management component

Comment: @Peter so, directed acyclic graph (DAG) for data-structure (this is what my colleagues hinted at also)